# I created a custom UserModel in Django and when i make migrations, it gives this error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' "

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-custom-user

I am new to django and i created a CustomUserModel and a form for user registration. But when i make migration, it gives me the following error:

```
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\ibm\programs\WebDevelopment\pFolio\pFolio\urls.py", line 19,
> in <module>
>     from users import views as userViews   File "C:\Users\ibm\programs\WebDevelopment\pFolio\users\views.py", line 3,
> in <module>
>     from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, ProfileForm   File "C:\Users\ibm\programs\WebDevelopment\pFolio\users\forms.py", line 9,
> in <module>
>     class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):   File "C:\Users\ibm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
> line 258, in __new__
>     apply_limit_choices_to=False,   File "C:\Users\ibm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
> line 142, in fields_for_model
>     opts = model._meta AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta
```

Here are my various file:

**models.py** I made a CustomUserModel that is inherited from AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin and another Profile model which has OneToOne realation with user and stores the profile pic and bio of the user. the profile pic has 4 default values based on their gender.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.

class CustomAccountsManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, date_of_birth, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an E-mail address'))

        other_fields.setdefault('is_activate', True)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, first_name=first_name, date_of_birth=date_of_birth, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, date_of_birth, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_activate', True)
        return self.create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, date_of_birth, **other_fields)

class CustomUserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=8)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='N', choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('T', 'Transgender'), ('N', 'NonBinary')))
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountsManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'date_of_birth']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name

class Profile(models.Model): #IGNORE THIS CLASS
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    default_pic_mapping = { 'M': 'defM.jpg', 'F': 'defF.jpg', 'N': 'defNB.jpg', 'T': 'defT.jpg'}

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} profile'

    def get_img_url(self):
        if not self.img:
            return settings.MEDIA_URL+(self.default_pic_mapping[self.gender])
        return self.img.url
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, ProfileForm
from django.contrib import messages


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        forms = UserRegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'title':    'User Registration',
        'forms':     forms
    }
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=False)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField()
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('T', 'Transgender'), ('N', 'NonBinary')), initial='N')
    
    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = [
            'user_name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'gender',
            'date_of_birth',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a `str` (string), you need to have a model object there instead, probably `User` (or a custom user model if you created one in your `models.py`):

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    # rest of your code
```